# Row press react native

Tags: react-native, navigation

How to navigate to another screen or do any action on row press using 'react-native-table-component'

```
import { Table, Row, TouchableRow } from "react-native-table-component";
```

Comment: Share your code!!

Comment: {data.map((entry, index) => (
          
          <Row
            key={index}
            data={reduceDataForScreenSize(
              entry,
              breakpoint,
              smallScreenIndices,
              mediumScreenIndices
            )}
            style={styles.dataRow}
            textStyle={styles.text}
            
          >
            </Row>
          
        ))}